# Handling Apostrophes with Angular2 TitleCasePipe

Tags: angular

My team is using pipes in Angular2/4 to transform text.  We're trying to use the [TitleCasePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe) found in '@angular/common' to make user-entered strings Title Case (i.e. "A Title in Title Case").

The string "tim's request" should be transformed to "Tim's Request", but the pipe is changing it to "Tim'S Request" with a capital "S".

How are other people working around this?

Answer (score 0):

Make your own pipe,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'mytitlecase', pure: false})

export class TitleCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: string): string {
    let words=input.length === 0 ? [''] :input.split(' ');
    let inputCapitalize=words.map(x=>x.length>1?x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+x.substring(1):x.toLowerCase()).join(' ');
    return inputCapitalize.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+inputCapitalize.substring(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next snippet and extend it.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'titleCase'
})
export class TitleCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    if (!value) { return null; }

    let words = value.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (let index = 0; index < words.length; index++) {
      const element = words[index];
      if (index > 0 && this.isPreposition(words[index])) { words[index] = element.toLowerCase(); }
      else { words[index] = this.toTitleCase(element); }
    }
    return words.join(' ');
  }

  private toTitleCase(value: string): string {
    return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase().concat(value.slice(1).toLowerCase());
  }

  private isPreposition(value: string): boolean {
    const Prepositions = ['of', 'the', 'in', 'on', 'at'];
    if (Prepositions.indexOf(value) >= 0) { return true; }
    return false;
  }
}
```